# Chinese fonts are not visible in programs installed in Wine

Tags: wine, fonts, chinese

I have installed Wine on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I run any program containing Chinese fonts, it shows some box type structure.

Tried:
update, installing Chinese fonts in Ubuntu, adding Chinese language under system settings. None of them worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, u must download wqy-microhei.ttc font online (https://github.com/anthonyfok/fonts-wqy-microhei/blob/master/wqy-microhei.ttc)

After saving this Regedit file on pc (https://gist.github.com/swordfeng/c3fd6b6fcf6dc7d7fa8a)

Font file copy to wine folder under C: drive folder, under Windows folder, under Font (/home/YOURUSERNAME/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts)

If you cant see the .wine folder, enter any folder and push keyboard Ctrl+H (show/hide the hidden folder)

And the last one you have downloaded regedit file. Steps:

1. Download winetricks (sudo apt-get install winetricks)
2. Open wine tricks app
3. First screen select 'Select the default wineprefix' and click OK (go to next)
4. Select the option to 'Run regedit'. You will see the windows registry editor screen.
5. Click on bar 'Registry > Import Registry File'
6. Select downloaded registry file and import.
7. Finish!

I hope it helps you. I also use some software that has Chinese font. Wine doesn't support some distro maybe.

Comment: This one worked fine

Comment: Actually copying any ttf font in /home/user_name/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts work well

Comment: Not work well in evernote 6.20.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the locales in Wine rather than a font issue. I had the same problem with most popular Bulgarian dictionary for Windows (SA Dictionary). You should set correct value of the `LANG` variable after `WINEPREFIX` within the `Exec=` directive in the `.desctop` file that run your application. In my case this is `LANG=bg_BG.UTF-8`. Here is example how my `.desctop` looks like to work correctly:

```bsh
user@host:~/Desktop$ cat Diction.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Diction
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/spas/.wine" LANG=bg_BG.UTF-8 wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/spas/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/Diction.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/spas/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/SADiction
Icon=D7E1_Diction.0
StartupWMClass=diction.exe
```

Type `locale` to to find the current values of the locales in the terminal.

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
where will I find the .desctop file and how to edit that?
can you please elaborate, thanks a lot

Comment: where will I find the .desctop file and how to edit that?
can you please elaborate, thanks a lot

Comment: @JobayerShajal How do you start the application? Through the command line or by clicking on a icon that is on your desktop?

Comment: from a .exe icon located in a file in desktop,

Comment: clicking on .exe file icon@pacho

Comment: @JobayerShajal: Ok. 1) start `gesdit`; 2) In the `File` menu choose `Open`; 3) Navigate to your Desktop and select the icon. 4) Copy the content , pate it in https://paste.ubuntu.com/ , and provide the link, please.

Comment: it gives a lot of texts looks like aliens' secret words

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/2ecc8f89830c915dea804553d7a25344.html

Comment: link to screenshot of total file

Comment: @JobayerShajal, I think I got it, you run directly the `.exe` and it is not installed within wine's folders. In this case try try these steps: 1) open terminal; 2) execute this command: `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 wine ~/Desktop/green/<file-name>.exe` (change <file-name> with the actual one)l you can just type `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 wine ` and drag and drop the file from Nautilus into the Terminal.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PjpyjrYSJN/

Comment: this is the out put

Comment: @JobayerShajal. Please try to go into the directory first `cd ~/Desktop/green/`, and then execute the command `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 wine 学宝客 户端.exe`. If this finally succeed I will rewrite my answer in a way how do create `.desktop` launcher for your application.

Comment: got the same output

Answer (score 0):

I don't have wine env, but gut- feeling tells that you could try to install Chinese fonts in wine

> /usr/share/wine/fonts

where the fonts is loaded from

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows 10 iso image you can extract `sources/install.wim` from it and from this `wim` file you can extract all the true type fonts using `wimextract` tool

```
wimextract install.wim 1 /Windows/{Fonts/"*".{ttf,ttc},System32/Licenses/neutral/"*"/"*"/license.rtf} --dest-dir fonts
```

Now you can use wine explorer to copy/paste all the fonts into `windows/Font` directory.