# No text in message writing area on WeChat with Wine and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, fonts

After solving the [non-rendering Chinese fonts with regedit](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073931/292615) WeChat is mostly working.
However, the message typing area does not display the text being typed.

Observed behaviour:

- Typed text is being correctly rendered in the top left Search box;
- Text is **not** being rendered in message typing area;
- One is still able to send messages correctly by typing something and pressing `Send (S)` or pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (You just can't see whatever you're typing.)

[image]

Terminal output whenever a character is typed in the writing area:

```
0009:fixme:richedit:fnTextSrv_TxDraw 0x2919368: STUB
0009:fixme:richedit:ME_GetTextEx GETTEXTEX flags 0x00000004 not supported
```

**System details:**

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- wine-3.21 (Staging)
- WINEARCH=win32
- WeChat 2.6.6.25

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit deeper and googling the *fixme* error lead me [here](http://wine.1045685.n8.nabble.com/Bug-44366-New-WeChat-does-not-render-typed-text-td5948718.html).

Turns out running `winetricks riched20` will solve this problem.